# FileNotFound when reading the IIS applicationHost.config file

Tags: xml, iis

Why I get FileNotFound using this code? if I move the applicationHost.config file to another directory such as c:\temp it will read just fine.

```
const string IIS_CONFIG_FILE = 
@"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config";
string xml = File.ReadAllText(IIS_CONFIG_FILE);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));
```

It has to do with the directory because I can't even open a simple Test.xml file there. I used Process Monitor from SysInternals but nothing is traced. Very weird.

Thank you
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to read such 64 bit only file in a 32 bit application, then Windows leads you to the equivalent WOW64 file path, which indeed does not exist.

Comment: huh? never heard that before. I know the file is at C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config and my console app is target to Any CPU and my OS is 64 bits. I am not following. I am not loading anything from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config

Comment: @Max when your process is running, check in Windows Task Manager whether it is marked as a 32 bit process. Of course, there are many other ways to check its runtime bitness.

Comment: oh yeah it is markes as *32. The check box "Prefer 32 bits" was checked. I never noticed that option before. Thank you so much!

Comment: One problem with this is that how can I develop one script to run in both 32 and 64 bits? if I run my process as 32bits and just want to load a xml file pointing directly to the path C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config" and it fails, that is just stupid. Now I cant compile this as 64bits and run it in 32 bits machines.

Comment: @Max the only case you cannot support is a 32 bit process running on 64 bit machine, as IIS core is purely 64 bit there. Don't worry about 32 bit machine, as IIS core will be 32 bit there and there would be no WOW64.